# How to put constraints on type variable of kind `Constraint`?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, gadt

I'm playing around with the `ConstraintKinds` extension of GHC.
I have the following data type, which is just a box for things fulfilling some one parameter constraint `c`:

```
data Some (c :: * -> Constraint) where
    Some :: forall a. c a => a -> Some c
```

For example, I could construct a box with some kind of number (arguably not very useful).

```
x :: Some Num
x = Some (1 :: Int)
```

Now, as long as `c` includes the constraint `Show`, I could provide an instance of `Show (Some c)`.

```
instance ??? => Show (Some c) where
    show (Some x) = show x    -- Show dictionary for type of x should be in scope here
```

But how do I express this requirement in the instance context (marked with `???`)?

I cannot use an equality constraint (`c ~ Show`), because the two are not necessarily equal. `c` could be `Num`, which implies, but is not equal to, `Show`.

**Edit**

I realised that this cannot be possible in general.

If you have two values of type `Some Eq`, it is not possible to compare them for equality. They could be of different types that each have their own notion of equality.

What applies to `Eq` applies to any type class in which the type parameter appears on the right hand side of the first function arrow (like the second `a` in `(==) :: a -> a -> Bool`).

Considering that there is no way to create a constraint expressing "this type variable is not used beyond the first arrow", I don't think it is possible to write the instance I want to write.

Comment: Since `Num` no longer requires a `Show` instance it might be helpful to find a different example.

Comment: Take a look at the [constraints](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package. I don't think it will let you do what you want to do, but it may give you inspiration as to how you can accomplish this.

Comment: I don't think this can be done unless you use `??? = Foo c` and `Foo` is a custom class to this purpose on the line of `class Foo c where fooShow :: c a => a -> String`, which needs to be instantiated manually with all the suitable `c`s (which I understand it's not your aim).

Comment: @user2407038, it looks like the `Class` class in that package is the closest Edward Kmett was able to get to this. I would guess you'd probably need to change the type checker to go the rest of the way.

Comment: @user2407038 Thank you, that pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closest we are able to get is a `Class1` class that reifys the relationship between a class and a single superclass constraint as a class. It's based on the [`Class`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.4.1.3/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t:Class) from [constraints](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints).

First, we'll take a short tour of the constraints package. A [`Dict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.4.1.3/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t:Dict) captures the dictionary for a [`Constraint`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.4.1.3/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t:Constraint)

```
data Dict :: Constraint -> * where
  Dict :: a => Dict a
```

`:-` captures that one constraint entails another. If we have `a :- b`, whenever we have the constraint `a` we can produce the dictionary for the constraint `b`.

```
newtype a :- b = Sub (a => Dict b)
```

We need a proof similar to `:-`, we need to know that `forall a. h a :- b a`, or `h a => Dict (b a)`.

#### Single Inheritance

Actually implementing this for `class`es with just single inheritance requires the kitchen sink of language extensions, including `OverlappingInstances`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

import Data.Constraint
```

We'll define the class of constraints of kind `k -> Constraint` where the constraint has a single superclass.

```
class Class1 b h | h -> b where
    cls1 :: h a :- b a
```

We're now equipped to tackle our example problem. We have a class `A` that requires a `Show` instance.

```
 class Show a => A a
 instance A Int
```

`Show` is a superclass of `A`

```
instance Class1 Show A where
    cls1 = Sub Dict
```

We want to write `Show` instances for `Some`

```
data Some (c :: * -> Constraint) where
    Some :: c a => a -> Some c
```

We can `Show` a `Some Show`.

```
instance Show (Some Show) where
    showsPrec x (Some a) = showsPrec x a
```

We can `Show` a `Some h` whenever `h` has a single superclass `b` and we could show `Some b`.

```
instance (Show (Some b), Class1 b h) => Show (Some h) where
    showsPrec x (Some (a :: a)) = 
        case cls1 :: h a :- b a of
            Sub Dict -> showsPrec x ((Some a) :: Some b)
```

This lets us write

```
x :: Some A
x = Some (1 :: Int)

main = print x
```

Comment: Interesting. This doesn't work if `c` has other super classes than `Show` because of the functional dependency, right?

Comment: It does work. Multiple super classes are actually a single constraint (a product of constraints).

Comment: So, the only downside is that you have to define that extra class `A`.

Comment: @AndrásKovács It would work for constraints of kind `Constraint`, these constraints have kind `* -> Constraint`; I don't think we can make a product of them without some trickery I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt `A` isn't an extra class, it's an example of an existing constraint that you would use in `Some A`. The extra work is defining the `Class1 Show A` instance for everything like `A`.

Comment: @Cirdec Understood, I was confused about the meaning of `A`. This seems to be the closest you can get to what I want.

Comment: That one you snuck in at the end, `OverlappingInstances`, is the only one that bothers me. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: @dfeuer I didn't sneak it in, `OvelappingInstances` was the only extension worth calling out explicitly in the text. For single inheritance it would be avoidable if you could add a constraint to `Class1` so the compiler could prove that `b ~ h` doesn't hold. Unfortunately, there's no constraint backtracking, not even through closed type families for closed data kinds. Adding e.g. `type family Equal a b :: Bool where Equal a a = True ; Equal a b = False` and `class (Equal b h ~ False) => Class1 b h | h -> b where cls1 :: h a :- b a` doesn't help.

Comment: For classes with multiple super classes, use `class (p a, q a) => (&) (p :: k -> Constraint) (q :: k -> Constraint) (a :: k); instance (p a, q a) => (&) p q a` which allows you to write `instance Class1 (A & B) C`. This is essentially the same as writing `type (&) p q a = (p a, q a)` but allows `&` to be partially applied.

Answer (score 2):

The new `QuantifiedConstraints` extension allows this.

```
class (a => b) => Implies a b where
instance (a => b) => Implies a b where
instance (forall a. c a `Implies` Show a) => Show (Some c) where
  show (Some x) = show x
```

Within the body of the `Show` instance, it is as if there is a

```
instance forall a. Implies (c a) (Show a)
```

in scope. If you then have `T :: Type` and know `c T`, then the superclass of `c T => Show T` of the specialized `Implies (c T) (Show T)` instance allows you to derive `Show T`. It is necessary to use `Implies` instead of a straight `forall a. c a => Show a` constraint. This incorrect constraint acts like

```
instance forall a. c a => Show a
```

which overlaps with every `Show` instance, [causing weird breakage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56573436/5684257). Forcing an indirection through the superclass of an otherwise useless constraint fixes everything.

Comment: I still don't understand *how* that fixes everything.

Comment: If you use the bad constraint and want, I don’t know, `Show Int`, there are two instances—the one from the quantified constraint and the global one—and GHC will pick one as it feels like it. If it picks the global one, congrats, you’ve got a time bomb; if it picks the quantified one, you get an insoluble `c Int` want. If you use `Implies`, there is only 1 `Show Int` and it’s fine. Meanwhile, for the type inside `Some`, you now have 0 `Show` instances. After (and only after) this failure, you can search the superclasses of the known constraints, finding the `Show` in the `Implies`.

Comment: [AFAICT it’s sanctioned as “expected behavior”.](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/14877) I don’t like it much, either, but it’s probably a bug if it ever doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make `Some c` an instance of `Show`, except trivially.

You want to `show` the `a` inside `Some`, but that variable is existentially quantified, so we cannot depend on any knowledge of the type of `a`. In particular, we have no way of knowing that `a` is an instance of `Show`.

**EDIT:** I'll expand on my answer. 
Even with more machinery, and giving up on a `Show` instance, I still don't think what you want is possible because of the existential quantification.

First I'll rewrite `Some` in a more familiar form

```
data Dict p where
    Dict :: p a => a -> Dict p
```

The usual way to talk about "constraints implying constraints" is with the concept of constraint entailment.

```
data p :- q where
    Sub :: p a => Dict q -> p :- q
```

We can think about a value of type `p :- q` as a proof that if the constraint `forall a. p a` holds, then `forall a. q a` follows.

Now we try to write a sensible `show`-ish function

```
showD :: p :- Show -> Dict p -> String
showD (Sub (Dict a)) (Dict b) = show b
```

At a glance, this might work. We have brought the following constraints into scope (forgive the pseudo-`exists` syntax)

```
(0) p :: * -> Constraint
(1) exists a. p a           -- (Dict p)
(2) exists b. p b => Show b -- (p :- Show)
```

But now things fall apart, GHC rightfully complains:

```
main.hs:10:33:
    Could not deduce (Show a2) arising from a use of `show' 
    from the context (p a)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 Sub :: forall (p :: * -> Constraint) (q :: * -> Constraint) a.
                        (p a) => 
                        Dict q -> p :- q,
               in an equation for `showD' 
      at main.hs:10:8-19                    
    or from (Show a1) 
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 Dict :: forall (p :: * -> Constraint) a. (p a) => a -> Dict p, 
               in an equation for `showD'
      at main.hs:10:13-18 
    or from (p a2)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 Dict :: forall (p :: * -> Constraint) a. (p a) => a -> Dict p,
               in an equation for `showD'
      at main.hs:10:23-28
```

because it is impossible to unify the `a` from `(1)` with the `b` from `(2)`.

This is the same essential idea that is used throughout the `constraints` package mentioned in the comments.

Comment: The question is how to make, say, `Some Num` an instance of `Show` where `Num` implies `Show`. (It doesn't any more, but that's besides the point.)

Comment: The OP wrote that `instance c ~ Show => Show (Some c) ` would work, but is stricter than it could be. (I did not downvote this, but this might explain who did)

Comment: @cdk Your assertion is correct in vanilla Haskell. However, I have made use of the `GADTs` extension, which means that matching on `Some` brings an instance of `c a` into scope. The problem is proving to the compiler that `c a ~ Num a` implies `Show a`.