# Why is using QuantifiedConstraints to specify a subclass of a typeclass also demanding an instance of the subclass?

Tags: haskell, quantified-constraints

I'm playing around with a multikinded tagless encoding of `Free`

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
module Free where
import GHC.Types

type (a :: k) ~> (b :: k) = Morphism k a b

newtype Natural (f :: j -> k) (g :: j -> k) = 
  Natural { getNatural :: forall (x :: j). f x ~> g x }

type family Morphism k :: k -> k -> Type where
  Morphism Type = (->)
  Morphism (j -> k) = Natural

class DataKind k where
  data Free :: (k -> Constraint) -> k -> k
  interpret :: forall (cls :: k -> Constraint) (u :: k) (v :: k). 
               cls v => (u ~> v) -> (Free cls u ~> v)
  call :: forall (cls :: k -> Constraint) (u :: k). 
          u ~> Free cls u

instance DataKind Type where
  newtype Free cls u = Free0
    { runFree0 :: forall v. cls v => (u ~> v) -> v }
  interpret f = \(Free0 g) -> g f
  call = \u -> Free0 $ \f -> f u
```

I can write `Semigroup` instances for `Free Semigroup` and `Free Monoid` without a problem:

```hs
instance Semigroup (Free Semigroup u) where
  Free0 g <> Free0 g' = Free0 $ \f -> g f <> g' f

instance Semigroup (Free Monoid u) where
  Free0 g <> Free0 g' = Free0 $ \f -> g f <> g' f
```

These instances are the same, and will be for any other subclass of `Semigroup`.

I want to use `QuantifiedConstraints` so I can just write one instance for all subclasses of `Semigroup`:

```hs
instance (forall v. cls v => Semigroup v) => Semigroup (Free cls u) where
  Free0 g <> Free0 g' = Free0 $ \f -> g f <> g' f
```

But the compiler (GHC-8.6.3) complains that it's unable to deduce `cls (Free cls u)`:

```
Free.hs:57:10: error:
    • Could not deduce: cls (Free cls u)
        arising from a use of ‘GHC.Base.$dmsconcat’
      from the context: forall v. cls v => Semigroup v
        bound by the instance declaration at Free.hs:57:10-67
    • In the expression: GHC.Base.$dmsconcat @(Free cls u)
      In an equation for ‘GHC.Base.sconcat’:
          GHC.Base.sconcat = GHC.Base.$dmsconcat @(Free cls u)
      In the instance declaration for ‘Semigroup (Free cls u)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        sconcat :: GHC.Base.NonEmpty (Free cls u) -> Free cls u
          (bound at Free.hs:57:10)
   |
57 | instance (forall v. cls v => Semigroup v) => Semigroup (Free cls u) where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Free.hs:57:10: error:
    • Could not deduce: cls (Free cls u)
        arising from a use of ‘GHC.Base.$dmstimes’
      from the context: forall v. cls v => Semigroup v
        bound by the instance declaration at Free.hs:57:10-67
      or from: Integral b
        bound by the type signature for:
                   GHC.Base.stimes :: forall b.
                                      Integral b =>
                                      b -> Free cls u -> Free cls u
        at Free.hs:57:10-67
    • In the expression: GHC.Base.$dmstimes @(Free cls u)
      In an equation for ‘GHC.Base.stimes’:
          GHC.Base.stimes = GHC.Base.$dmstimes @(Free cls u)
      In the instance declaration for ‘Semigroup (Free cls u)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        stimes :: b -> Free cls u -> Free cls u (bound at Free.hs:57:10)
   |
57 | instance (forall v. cls v => Semigroup v) => Semigroup (Free cls u) where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When I add this as context for the instance, it compiles fine:

```hs
instance (cls (Free cls u), forall v. cls v => Semigroup v) => Semigroup (Free cls u) where
  Free0 g <> Free0 g' = Free0 $ \f -> g f <> g' f
```

The added context is a little verbose, but since the whole point of `Free` is that `cls (Free cls u)` is always true, not onerous.

What I don't understand is *why* GHC needs to be able to conclude `cls (Free cls u)` for the subclass of `Semigroup` for the `Semigroup` instance to compile. I tried replacing the definition of `(<>)` with `undefined` and got the same error, so I think the issue is not in the implementation itself but in the declaration of the instance; probably due to some aspect of `QuantifiedConstraints` I don't understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error messages state these errors come from the default definitions of `sconcat` and `stimes`. Quantified contexts act like `instance`s: within your `instance Semigroup (Free cls v)`, it's as if there is an `instance cls v => Semigroup v` in scope. `instance`s are chosen by matching. `sconcat` and `stimes` want `Semigroup (Free cls v)`, so they match that want against the context `instance forall z. cls z => Semigroup z`, succeed with `z ~ Free cls v`, and get a further wanted of `cls (Free cls v)`. This happens even though we also have a recursive `instance _etc => Semigroup (Free cls v)` around. Remember, we assume that typeclass instances are coherent; there should be no difference whether the quantified context is used or the currently defined instance is used, so GHC just picks whichever instance it feels like using.

However, this is not a good situation. The quantified context *overlaps* with our instance (actually, it overlaps with *every* `Semigroup` instance), which is alarming. If you try something like `(<>) = const (Free0 _etc) ([1, 2] <> [3, 4])`, you get a similar error, because the quantified context overshadows the real `instance Semigroup [a]` in the library. I think including some ideas from [issue 14877](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/14877) can make this less uncomfortable:

```
class (a => b) => Implies a b
instance (a => b) => Implies a b
instance (forall v. cls v `Implies` Semigroup v) => Semigroup (Free cls u) where
  Free0 g <> Free0 g' = Free0 $ \f -> g f <> g' f
```

Using `Implies` here means that the quantified context no longer matches the want for `Semigroup (Free cls v)` which is instead discharged by recursion. However, the requirement behind the constraint doesn't change. Essentially, we keep the requirement fragment of the quantified constraint, for the user, that `Semigroup v` should be implied by `cls v`, while slapping a safety on the discharge fragment, for the implementation, so it doesn't muck up our constraint resolution. The `Implies` constraint still can and has to be used to prove the `Semigroup v` constraint in `(<>)`, but it's considered as a last resort after the explicit `Semigroup` instances are exhausted.

Comment: Would it help any if the `QuantifiedConstraints` syntax distinguished between superclass and instance constraints? I'm rather sad that the committee rejected my suggestion that implication constraints (ill behaved) get a separate extension from quantified constraints (well behaved). I really think the former still need significantly more R & D to get right.

Comment: You mean you want arrows `class S => C` and `instance R => H` such that, in `f :: (instance R => H) => T`, you get `instance R => H` in scope (exactly like the current extension), but, for `g :: (class S => C) => T`, you get `class S => C` (adding `S` to whatever superclasses `C` already had)? I don't think that helps: `instance` constraints *are* constraints. Even without quantified constraints, we need to derive wanteds from the superclasses of instance constraints. Adding quantification is enough to emulate `class` constraints. Separating `class` constraints would not contain the wonkiness.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you're saying, which of course doesn't mean you're wrong. In the latter case, it would probably look more like `(forall a. class S a => c a) => T c`. But as you suggest, that may not help the problem any. Do you see what I mean about quantification behaving better than implication?

Comment: @dfeuer Oh, you mean you want `forall vars. Ctx vars` to be kosher but `Req => Deriv` to be gated behind another extension? I don't think the latter behaves significantly worse than the former. Both let you get overlapping instances, which is the real source of the weirdness, but that the latter just causes errors sometimes instead of silently accepting. I just wish it were better documented.

Comment: The usual problem with implication constraints is that the local/global instance chosen will affect the way resolution proceeds, since you'll get different wanteds; resolution can fail because the instance constraints of the chosen instance can't be satisfied even though there's another instance in scope whose constraints can be. With plain quantified constraints, I don't believe that happens, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, that all makes sense. I can't say I have any opinions on the matter. I do wonder: is there any trick, `Implies` or a generalization thereof, that can always resolve such conflicts? As long as there is one I can't complain.