# Why does this usage of quantified constraints fail to compile:

Tags: haskell, quantified-constraints

Consider the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}

data SomeMaybe c t where
  SomeNothing :: SomeMaybe c t
  SomeJust :: c t => t -> SomeMaybe c t

instance (forall b. c b => Semigroup b) => Semigroup (SomeMaybe c u) where
  x <> y = case x of
    SomeNothing -> y
    SomeJust x' -> case y of
      SomeNothing -> x
      SomeJust y' -> SomeJust (x' <> y')
```

I get the following error:

```
src/Filename.hs: error:
    • Could not deduce: c (SomeMaybe c u)
        arising from a use of ‘GHC.Base.$dmsconcat’
      from the context: forall b. c b => Semigroup b
        bound by the instance declaration
        at src/Filename.hs
    • In the expression: GHC.Base.$dmsconcat @(SomeMaybe c u)
      In an equation for ‘GHC.Base.sconcat’:
          GHC.Base.sconcat = GHC.Base.$dmsconcat @(SomeMaybe c u)
      In the instance declaration for ‘Semigroup (SomeMaybe c u)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        sconcat :: GHC.Base.NonEmpty (SomeMaybe c u) -> SomeMaybe c u
          (bound at src/Filename.hs)
```

I believe the issue is the default implementation of `sconcat` and `stimes` which fail to typecheck.

However I don't quite understand why this is the case.

*Background note:*

For a brief background on why I'm trying to make such a type like `SomeMaybe`, I'm making my datatypes ["barbies"](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies-2.0.4.0) so then for example, I can use [`bpure`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies-2.0.4.0/docs/Barbies.html#v:bpure) like so:

```
instance ApplicativeB f => Semigroup (f MyType) where
  (<>) = bzipWith (<>)

instance ApplicativeB f => Monoid (f MyType) where
  mempty = bpure mempty
```

But this only works if `MyType a` is a monoid for ALL `a`.

**Edit: Workaround**

Changing the `Semigroup` definition to the following:

```
semigroupOp :: forall c t. (forall b. c b => Semigroup b) => SomeMaybe c t -> SomeMaybe c t -> SomeMaybe c t
semigroupOp x y = case x of
  SomeNothing -> y
  SomeJust x' -> case y of
    SomeNothing -> x
    SomeJust y' -> SomeJust (x' <> y')

instance forall c t. (forall b. c b => Semigroup b) => Semigroup (SomeMaybe c t) where
  (<>) :: (forall b. c b => Semigroup b) => SomeMaybe c t -> SomeMaybe c t -> SomeMaybe c t
  (<>) = semigroupOp
  sconcat :: NonEmpty (SomeMaybe c t) -> (SomeMaybe c t)
  sconcat (a :| as) = go a as where
    go :: SomeMaybe c t -> [SomeMaybe c t] -> SomeMaybe c t
    go x = \case
      [] -> x
      (c : cs) -> semigroupOp x (go c cs)
  stimes n = \case
    SomeNothing -> SomeNothing
    SomeJust x -> SomeJust (stimes n x)
```

which gets this to compile, although it's not clear *why* I need to do this?
In particular, why I can't just call `<>` instead of `semigroupOp` in `sconcat`?

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question, but `(forall b. c b => Semigroup b)` is stronger than it needs to be. The original code compiles if you switch this to `(c u => Semigroup u)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is using QuantifiedConstraints to specify a subclass of a typeclass also demanding an instance of the subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573436/why-is-using-quantifiedconstraints-to-specify-a-subclass-of-a-typeclass-also-dem)

Answer (score -1):

Removed from the question cause it's an answer:

> Answering my own question, changing the Semigroup definition to the following:
>
> ```
> semigroupOp :: forall c t. (forall b. c b => Semigroup b) => SomeMaybe c t -> SomeMaybe c t -> SomeMaybe c t
> semigroupOp x y = case x of
>   SomeNothing -> y
>   SomeJust x' -> case y of
>     SomeNothing -> x
>     SomeJust y' -> SomeJust (x' <> y')
>
> instance forall c t. (forall b. c b => Semigroup b) => Semigroup (SomeMaybe c t) where
>   (<>) :: (forall b. c b => Semigroup b) => SomeMaybe c t -> SomeMaybe c t -> SomeMaybe c t
>   (<>) = semigroupOp
>   sconcat :: NonEmpty (SomeMaybe c t) -> (SomeMaybe c t)
>   sconcat (a :| as) = go a as where
>     go :: SomeMaybe c t -> [SomeMaybe c t] -> SomeMaybe c t
>     go x = \case
>       [] -> x
>       (c : cs) -> semigroupOp x (go c cs)
>   stimes n = \case
>     SomeNothing -> SomeNothing
>     SomeJust x -> SomeJust (stimes n x)
> ```
>
> solves the issue.

Comment: This shouldn't be in the answer section because it ends in a question. Answers don't end in question marks.

Comment: This shouldn't be in the question because it starts in "Answering my own Question" period. A follow up question honestly does belong in a new Post all together.

Comment: To me this reads like added details to the question, not an answer.