# How do I allow one Constraint to imply another in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I am playing around with some type-level programming, and I wanted to implement some interesting instances for things like `Num`, allowing mathematical operators on fixed-length `Vector`s.

Some of the pertinent parts I currently have are as follows (in addition to a `Functor` instance):

```hs
data Nat = One
         | Succ Nat
             deriving (Show, Eq)

data Vector (n :: Nat) a where
  VecSing :: a -> Vector 'One a
  (:+) :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector ('Succ n) a

instance Num a => Num (Vector 'One a) where
  (+) = vecZipWith (+)
  (*) = vecZipWith (*)
  abs = fmap abs
  signum = fmap signum
  negate = fmap negate
  fromInteger = VecSing . fromInteger

instance (Num a, Num (Vector n a)) => Num (Vector ('Succ n) a) where
  (+) = vecZipWith (+)
  (*) = vecZipWith (*)
  abs = fmap abs
  signum = fmap signum
  negate = fmap negate
  fromInteger a = fromInteger a :+ fromInteger a
```

However, I have come up with an issue when I actually want to *use* these instances. This is due to the fact, as much as I can surmise, that whenever I want to add two `Vector`s together, I have to specify that they are, in fact, instances of `Num`, such as in the below example.

```hs
addAndMultiply :: (Num a) => Vector n a -> Vector n a -> Vector n a -> Vector n a
addAndMultiply a b c = (a + b) * c
-- Compilation error snippet:
-- Could not deduce (Num (Vector n a)) arising from a use of `*'
--      from the context: Num a
```

What I would like is a way to imply that, when you have a `Num a`, any `Vector n a`s also fulfill the constraint `Num`.

I tried to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704163/how-to-put-constraints-on-type-variable-of-kind-constraint?noredirect=1&lq=1) solution, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983019/haskell-type-family-instance-with-type-constraints) one, but I don't think these are quite the same thing; the question-askers usually have a data type that takes a constraint, and does things with the boxed value, while I just want to implicitly imply a constraint from another one; or at least, I think I do.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Please let me know if any additional information is required; the current code base state can be seen at https://github.com/L0neGamer/matrix-pkg if you want to take a dive yourself.

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but: please don't write `Num` instances for non-scalar vector types. The behaviour of `fromIntegral` doesn't really make sense for those; this has led to some nasty hard-to-find bugs for me when using e.g. [`Linear.V3`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.21/docs/Linear-V3.html). The correct typeclass to instantiate is [`VectorSpace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html).

Comment: @leftaroundabout that's reasonable; this is mostly a project for my own entertainment, but I do like learning about the correct way to do things, so thanks for the VectorSpace recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you don't really need to deconstruct the size-parameter in any num/vector-space instances. Anyway the implementation basically just passes everything through to the `Functor` instance; if you also implement an `Applicative` one then you can to *everything* based on that, like

```
instance Num a => AdditiveGroup (Vector n a) where
  zeroV = pure 0
  negateV = fmap negate
  (^+^) = liftA2 (+)
instance Num a => VectorSpace (Vector n a) where
  type Scalar (Vector n a) = a
  μ *^ v = fmap (μ*) v
```

But of course this relies on first having that `Applicative` instance for really arbitrary `n`. This *should* intuitively be possible since both constructors of `Nat` give rise to instances, but actually the compiler needs some extra help in form of a typeclass. In the standard version of type-level nats, this is [`KnownNat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:KnownNat); for your own version you could do it like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures, TypeInType #-}
import Data.Kind

data NatS :: Nat -> Type where
  OneS :: NatS One
  SuccS :: KnownNat n => NatS (Succ n)

class KnownNat (n :: Nat) where
  natSing :: NatS n  -- I like to call such values “witnesses”, but
                     -- the conventional terminology is “singletons”.

instance KnownNat 'One where
  natSing = OneS
instance KnownNat n => KnownNat ('Succ n) where
  natSing = SuccS
```

Then base the functor instances on that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax, TypeApplications #-}
instance ∀ n . KnownNat n => Functor (Vector n) where
  fmap f = case natSing @n of
    OneS -> \(VecSing x) -> VecSing $ f x
    SuccS -> \(x :+ v) -> f x :+ fmap f v
```

Similarly for `Applicative`.

Then, for the `VectorSpace` etc. instances, you don't need to explicitly handle those singletons anymore, just mention `KnownNat n` and you'll be able to exploit the `Applicative` instance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me; I have implemented `Applicative`s in the manner described (having previously implemented `Functor`s without having to use `KnownNat`), but your code is complaining that couldn't deduce a "zeroV" for the AdditiveGroup.
The ability to define Applicatives and the like with only using one instance is nice though; previously I had to recursively define the instances (`instance Applicative (Vector 'One) where`, then `instance Applicative (Vector n) => Applicative (Vector ('Succ n)) where`)

Comment: The error about `zeroV` is because when you don't define it manually it tries to auto-generate an implementation based on Generics, but that doesn't work in this case. Just define `zeroV = pure 0`.

Comment: Alright, that fix worked; additionally, I had to add `KnownNat n` to the instances of `AdditiveGroup` and `VectorSpace`, and change `type Scalar (Vector a) = a` to `type Scalar (Vector n a) = a`.